# TextBoxFor Date object always shows time element

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

I am having a problem displaying/editing a date in MVC 3.

I have set up my data class property as follows (the data is actually provided by a Linq2Sql object):

```
[DisplayName("Date of Birth")]
[DisplayFormat(ApplyFormatInEditMode = true, DataFormatString = "{0:dd/MM/yyyy}", NullDisplayText = "")]
public DateTime DoB { get; set; }
```

In the view I then have:

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.DoB, new { @class = "date" })
```

The problem is, the text box always shows the time portion of the date, e.g. '18/10/2010 00:00:00'

I know I can get over this problem by using a standard Html.TextBox

```
@Html.TextBox("DoB", Model.DoB.ToShortDateString())
```

but I really want to be able to control this from the data model.

I have found articles on the web that suggest that this works, but I can't repeat their success.

Any help/advice would be appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you want the data annotations attributes such as `DisplayFormat` to have any effect you should use:

```
@Html.EditorFor(m => m.DoB)
```

Checkout the [following blog post](http://bradwilson.typepad.com/blog/2009/10/aspnet-mvc-2-templates-part-2-modelmetadata.html) from Brad Wilson which explains how model metadata works in ASP.NET MVC.

The drawback is that now you cannot specify the class anymore. One possible solution would be to do this:

```
<div class="input-date">
    @Html.EditorFor(m => m.DoB)
</div>
```

and then style:

```
.input-date input {
    ...
}
```

or you could also write a [custom DataAnnotationsModelMetadataProvider](http://aspadvice.com/blogs/kiran/archive/2009/11/29/Adding-html-attributes-support-for-Templates-_2D00_-ASP.Net-MVC-2.0-Beta_2D00_1.aspx) which would allow you to specify attributes such as class, size, maxlength, ... using data annotations.

Comment: The problem I have with this is that `EditorFor` does not allow you to apply `HTMLAttributes` like `TextBoxFor`. So how does somebody work around that problem that doesn't result in a dozen+ lines of code to simply add `class=` to the input?

Comment: @Eric, why not add the class to a containing div?

Comment: I do not have my elements contained within Divs. I really try to use CSS as much as possible to eliminate extraneous html markup. Also, that isn't really solving the problem of placing a class directly on an input.

Answer (score 0):

Correct usage is `[DataType(DataType.Date)]`

Comment: This did not appear to do anything

Answer (score 0):

I have stumbled upon this and had the same problems. I found splitting the display and model values allowed me to handle the display of a date in any format I wish:

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.DoB, new {@class="date",Value=Model.DoB.ToString(DateFormat.DdMmYyyy) })
```

This allows me to bind values to and from the model but I can handle the output format.