# Html TextBoxFor always shows my DateTime? value with a time included even when I override in asp.net mvc 2. why?

Tags: c#, html, asp.net-mvc-2, view, html-helper

I have an edit object view. In this view are several DateTime? properties that are using:

model.MyDateTime ) %>

I have an editor template named DateTime that is strongly typed against a DateTime? type. The view is declared as follows:

```
<%@ Control Language="C#" Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewUserControl<DateTime?>" %>

<% if( Model.HasValue ) { %>
    <%= Html.TextBoxFor( x => Model, Model.Value.ToShortDateString() ) %>
<% } else { %>
    <%= Html.TextBoxFor(x => Model) %>
<% } %>
```

The time portion is always displayed no matter what I do. I know the display template is being rendered. I've added static text for the if output as well as the else output and the former always shows. The incredibly odd thing is I can do:

```
<%= Html.Encode(Model.Value.ToShortDateString())   %>
```

And no time portion is displayed. I'm rather stumped. Below are the GET & POST actions I am using:

```
   public ActionResult EditAssociate(int? Oid)
    {
        if (!Oid.HasValue)
            return RedirectToAction("SelectReviewYearAndAssociate");
        MpaNonExemptData mpaNonExemptRecord = repository.getNonExemptDataByOid(Oid.Value);
        return View(mpaNonExemptRecord);
    }

[HttpPost]
public ActionResult EditAssociate(MpaNonExemptData associate)
{
    repository.updateNonExemptDataByOid(associate);
    return View(associate);
}
```

As you can see, it's really straightforward. Any thoughts?

I have looked at the following questions, but did not find an answer:

[TextBoxFor Date object always shows time element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5252546/textboxfor-date-object-always-shows-time-element)

[TextBoxFor Helper retains previous value even when model value is empty](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6221691/textboxfor-helper-retains-previous-value-even-when-model-value-is-empty)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use the `TextBox` helper inside your editor template as contrary to `TextBoxFor` it allows you to specify the value (the second argument of the `TextBoxFor` helper does not do what you think it does => it's simply used to pass html attributes to the generated field, not to set the value):

```
<%@ Control Language="C#" Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewUserControl<DateTime?>" %>

<% if(Model.HasValue) { %>
    <%= Html.TextBox("", Model.Value.ToShortDateString()) %>
<% } else { %>
    <%= Html.TextBox("") %>
<% } %>
```

Also if this is an editor template (which is what it seems to be) you need to include it with `Html.EditorFor(x => x.MyDateTime)` instead of `Html.DisplayFor(x => x.MyDateTime)` as shown in your example.

Comment: I meant to type EditorFor in the question. The code is actually using EditorFor currently. I could try using Html.TextBox like you say, but how do I handle naming the text box so this field gets data bound back to the model? Currently, using the TextBoxFor with the lambda expression is working as far as keeping the values tied to the object properties they go with.

Comment: @Jason, don't worry. `TextBox` will handle that for you. It takes into account the navigation property so that you can use any level of nesting you like and correct names will be generated for the input fields. And by the way that's close to how the original DateTime editor template is implemented : http://bradwilson.typepad.com/blog/2009/10/aspnet-mvc-2-templates-part-3-default-templates.html

Comment: Man, I tried it and would have bet money it was gonna bust, but it worked just like you said. That's pretty neat. Thanks for the input!

Answer (score 0):

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.YourDateField, 
new { @onkeydown = "return false;", @class = "yourCssClass", 
@Value = (Model.YourDateField.HasValue) ? 
Model.YourDateField.Value.ToShortDateString() : ""})
```